# how to get value of AMInputView is swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have this existing project and the textfields are on "AMInputView".
How to set a string or what is the member for AMInputView? To get the value?

Comment: But the  Type 'AMInputView' has no member 'text'. I can't find a documentation for AMInputView in Apple Dev site.

Comment: AMInputView is not a UITextField Object. The @IBOutlet is AMInputView

Comment: Check out the last comment

Comment: @SalmanGhumsani, thanks so much. It works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get and set the value of text `AMInputView` by using:

`AMInputView.textFieldView.text`